# Extend a CoffeeScript class loaded with RequireJS inside a TypeScript code

Tags: coffeescript, requirejs, typescript

Currently I have a large codebase developed with CoffeeScript and want to extend it with some TypeScript.

Let's say I have the following code in the `CoffeeClass.coffee` file:

```coffee
define 'CoffeeClass', ->
  class CoffeeClass
    foo: () -> 1
```

It is meant to be loaded through `require` in the following manner (let's call this file `CoffeeUser.coffee`):

```coffee
require ['CoffeeClass'], (CoffeeClass) ->
  class MyClass extends CoffeeClass
    foo: () -> super() + 1
  console.log (new MyClass().foo()) # => 2
```

Now it can be loaded in browser with the standard RequireJS markup:

```html
<script data-main="CoffeeUser.js" src="require.js"></script>
```

I want to extend the `CoffeeClass` from the TypeScript code. That's what I've tried:

First write a `CoffeeClass.d.ts` definiton file (I know it is wrong but it's showing what I'm trying to achieve):

```typescript
export class CoffeeClass {
  foo(): number;
}
```

And then try to use it from `TypeScriptUser.ts`:

```typescript
import CoffeeClass = require('CoffeeClass');
class TypeScriptUser extends CoffeeClass {
  foo(): number {
    return super.foo() + 1;
  }
}
```

But it won't compile partly because I cannot find the right syntax for the `d.ts` file and partly because I cannot properly tell the compiler how to extend the `CoffeeClass` (as far as I can tell the compiler cannot understand that `CoffeeClass` is really a *class* and not just a module).

So can I tell the TypeScript compiler that *the module* is *a class* here? If no, how would you recommend me to change the `CoffeeClass` design to extend it from TypeScript code and don't lose all the type safety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution. That's the special `export =` syntax. Here it is. `CoffeeClass.d.ts`:

```typescript
declare class CoffeeClass {
    foo(): number;
}

export = CoffeeClass;
```

And `TypeUser.ts`:

```typescript
/// <reference path="CoffeeClass.d.ts" />
import CoffeeClass = require('CoffeeClass')
class MyClass extends CoffeeClass {
    foo() {
        return super.foo() + 1;
    }
}

console.log(new MyClass().foo()); // => 2
```

Note that the compiler will infer the proper `require` call when compiling the code.